# Is there a way to do on demand flushing of WCF trace?

Tags: wcf, trace, flush

Just like there is a command to flush IIS7 logs:

```
netsh http flush logbuffer
```

I'm wondering is there a similar command to flush WCF trace log on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do an IIS reset, but this is only really an option when debugging on a developmnet box.

Comment: Thanks for reply, that's the only info I found out so far.

Comment: It's been a while and techincally your answer is correct so I accepted it.

Answer (score 29):

Setting the `autoflush="true"` in your `.config` file ensures that the trace sources flush to disk after each trace.

The following is a sample configuration file with `autoflush="true"`:

```
<configuration>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
   <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
                 propagateActivity="true">
     <listeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                      initializeData="e2eTraceTest.xml" />
    </listeners>
   </source>
  </sources>

  <trace autoflush="true" />

 </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

In addition, if by any chance you are willing to store your WCF trace in a database, you might want to check out this post:

- [**Stack Overflow: How can I enable WCF logging so that it writes to a Database?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923934/how-can-i-enable-wcf-logging-so-that-it-writes-to-a-database/1924014#1924014)'

This would allow you to view your WCF trace in real-time, without flushing it.

Comment: @Piotr: You may also want to consider the `autoflush=true` method, as described in the answer.

Comment: That's what I did eventually. However I would rather have buffering that would conserve resources and allowed flushing either on demand and on buffer overflow (and/or low resource usage). I just think that would be beneficial from server's perspective.

Comment: @Piotr: Yes, I agree with you.