# How can I enable WCF logging so that it writes to a Database?

Tags: database, wcf, logging, performance

I'd like to be able to log message information in a database, and I'm trying to decide how best to do that. Is it possible to configure the WCF logging mechanisms to write to a database instead of a file? Thanks.

Comment: Blog [Configuring WCF service to utilise Enterprise Library: Logging application to log data to database](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2011/11/07/configuring-wcf-service-to-utilise-enterprise-library-logging-application-to-log-data-to-database.aspx) has step-by-step instructions, how to configure 'Database Trace listener'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have two things:

- a proper config to enable .NET tracing
- a trace listener to capture the trace messages and store them in a database

**For #1**:
You need to turn on tracing in WCF first - you need an entry in `<system.serviceModel>` that enables tracing:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
          logEntireMessage="true"
          logMalformedMessages="false"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
          maxMessagesToLog="300000"
          maxSizeOfMessageToLog="200000"/>
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Next, you need to configure .NET tracing as such:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" 
              propagateActivity="true">
         <listeners>
            <add name="xml" />
         </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
         <listeners>
             <add name="xml" />
         </listeners>
      </source>
   </sources>
   <sharedListeners>
       <add name="xml" type="WcfTrace.Trace.WebTraceListener,WcfTrace.Trace" />
   </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Here, instead of the WebTraceListener, or other pre-defined listeners, you can also plug in your own database-oriented trace listener.

**For #2:**
You can - of course - write your own `SqlTraceListener` - or you can use one of the many ready-made solutions out there, for instance [this one here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Using_the_SqlTraceListener.aspx) (download the code from [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=UkadcDiagnostics&title=SqlTraceListener&referringTitle=Home)).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the whole SOAP-message, I would suggest to use log4net with custom   [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx) or IDispatchMessageInspector implementation, cause in this case you can write to log only what you need.
Otherwise, take marc_s's solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)